# How to Extract product dimensions from a string column having dimension contained within a string?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
dat=data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),
               details=c("lane_1_8x16X12_rt","lane_3_8x16_rt","lane_5_3X6_idf"))
```

Now, What I am looking for is the extract `8X16X12`, `8X16` and `3x6` in three difeerent rows of a newly created column.

Answer (score 2):

Could try:

```
dat$new <- gsub(".*_(.*)_.*$", "\\1", dat$details)
```

Output:

```
  id           details     new
1  1 lane_1_8x16X12_rt 8x16X12
2  2    lane_3_8x16_rt    8x16
3  3    lane_5_3X6_idf     3X6
```

Answer (score 2):

An option would be `str_extract` and make sure to ignore the case (`(?i)`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dat %>%
    mutate(new = str_extract(details, "(?i)(8X16X12|8X16|3x6)"))
#     id           details     new
#1  1 lane_1_8x16X12_rt 8x16X12
#2  2    lane_3_8x16_rt    8x16
#3  3    lane_5_3X6_idf     3X6
```

---

Another option based on position of sub string would be

```
word(dat$details, 3, sep="_")
#[1] "8x16X12" "8x16"    "3X6"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `read.table()`:

```
dat$details_new <- read.table(text = as.character(dat$details), 
                              sep = "_")[, 3]

  id           details details_new
1  1 lane_1_8x16X12_rt     8x16X12
2  2    lane_3_8x16_rt        8x16
3  3    lane_5_3X6_idf         3X6
```

Answer (score 2):

An R base solution

```
> transform(dat, 
            details_2 = sub(".*_(\\d+.*\\d+)_.*", "\\1", dat$details))
  id           details details_2
1  1 lane_1_8x16X12_rt   8x16X12
2  2    lane_3_8x16_rt      8x16
3  3    lane_5_3X6_idf       3X6
```

You can use `strsplit`

```
> dat$NewDetails <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(dat$details), "_"), "[", 3)
> dat
  id           details NewDetails
1  1 lane_1_8x16X12_rt    8x16X12
2  2    lane_3_8x16_rt       8x16
3  3    lane_5_3X6_idf        3X6
```

Answer (score 2):

This `stringr` solution should be flexible:

```
library(stringr)

string <- c("lane_1_8x16X12_rt","lane_3_8x16_rt","lane_5_3X6_idf")
str_extract_all(string, "(?i)\\d+x\\d+x*\\d*")
[[1]]
[1] "8x16x12"

[[2]]
[1] "8x16"

[[3]]
[1] "3x6"
```